# DUnitX can't work at 64-bit?

Tags: delphi, dunitx

DUnitX works if i select '32-bit Windows', however, when I change it to '64-bit Windows', it says

```
[dcc64 Fatal Error] RPMLibTestsX.dpr(14): F2613 Unit 'DUnitX.Windows.Console' not found.
```

is this expected?

I am using RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin  Update 2 (Delphi)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This dcu seems to be missing in the `{BDSLIB}\Win64\release` Folder (I checked on my installation)

The other one that is missing is `DUnitX.MemoryLeakMonitor.FastMM4.dcu`

In order to compile your project either change the config to Debug or explicitly add the DUnitX source folder to your project search path to compile from the sources.

Comment: on the 'All Configurations - All Platforms',  the search path already has "$(DUnitX);..\"  and I try the DEBUG it still doesn't work.

Comment: "I try the DEBUG it still doesn't work" - your screenshot clearly shows that your test project only has a release build configuration (which is not what the DUnitX Wizard creates - it has both debug and release config). So either add it back or recreate the project using the Wizard. Also as you can see in the Search Path window the `$(DUnitX)` line is grey which means that this path does not exist - because the `DUnitX` variable is not defined.

Comment: Thanks. you are right about the 'grey' invalid $(DUnitX). After I download DUnitX src and add it to the search path, it works.

Comment: While you now probably have the most recent version of the source you did not have to download it - it ships with RAD Studio (see `source\DunitX` directory in your RAD Studio installation directory)

Comment: Thanks. have raised a JIRA ticket:  https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16832